# The POM for org.picketlink.distribution:picketlink-jbas7:jar:2.8.0. is missing, no dependency information available

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, picketlink

I'm trying to run the picketlink quickstarts from:

https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-picketlink-quickstarts

More specifically:

https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-picketlink-quickstarts/tree/master/picketlink-federation-saml-idp-basic

But in each attempt to install the maven dependencies I get the next error:

```
Could not find artifact org.picketlink.distribution:picketlink-jbas7:jar:2.8.0.Beta1-SNAPSHOT
```

Here is the whole log after my `$ mvn clean package jboss-as:deploy`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building PicketLink Quickstart: picketlink-federation-saml-idp-basic 2.8.0.Beta1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.picketlink.distribution:picketlink-jbas7:jar:2.8.0.Beta1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.650 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-17T01:39:15-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/80M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project picketlink-federation-saml-idp-basic: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.picketlink.quickstarts:picketlink-federation-saml-idp-basic:war:2.8.0.Beta1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.picketlink.distribution:picketlink-jbas7:jar:2.8.0.Beta1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I've seen that you might need to add a settings.xml to your maven folder, but I don't know how to make or what to put in that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already said, maven is telling you that `org.picketlink.distribution:picketlink-jbas7:jar:2.8.0.Beta1-SNAPSHOT` dependency is missing and I believe this is because you didn't install it previously.

As I can see `jboss-picketlink-quickstarts` is a bunch of projects which have a parent `pom.xml` where you can find your project as a module:

```
<module>picketlink-federation-saml-idp-basic</module>
```

So, you have to clone the whole `jboss-picketlink-quickstarts` project and run `mvn install` from the parent project.

This will lead you with all dependencies that you will need resolved into your local maven repository (*usually `~/.m2/repository`*).

Try it, it will solve your dependency. Some times you have to call maven with `-U` to force `-SNAPSHOT` dependencies.

Hope it helps!